# How to convert large number of uint_8 into array of floats in C?

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, type-conversion

I'm reading (in binary format) a file of unsigned 8-bit integers, which I then need to convert to an array of floats. Normally I'd just do something like the following:

```
uint8_t *s1_tmp = (uint8_t *)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t)*num_elements);
float *s1 = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float)*num_elements);

fread(s1_tmp, sizeof(uint8_t), num_elements, file_id);

for(int i = 0; i < num_elements; i++){
    s1[i] = s1_tmp[i];
}

free(s1_tmp)
```

Uninspired to be sure, but it works. However, currently `num_elements` is around 2.7 million, so the process is super slow and IMO wasteful.

Is there a better way to read in the 8-bit integers as floats or convert the `uint8_t` array into a float array?

Comment: Have you looked at doing it using SIMD?

Comment: I am assuming that you are trying to save some space by storing `uint8_t` instead of `float`. Converting one by one is the best you can get.

Comment: Don't cast the return of `malloc`, best avoid casts completely if you may. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Comment: I'm running Visual C++, so the cast is necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, this is going to be I/O-bound from reading the data in.  Secondly, it's going to be memory-bound.  You'll get much better cache performance if you interleave the conversion with the reading.

Pick some reasonable buffer size that's large enough for good I/O performance but small enough to fit in your cache, maybe 8-32 KB or so.  Read in that much data, convert, and repeat.

For example:

```
#define BUFSIZE 16384
uint8_t *buffer = malloc(BUFSIZE);
float *s1 = malloc(num_elements * sizeof(float));

int total_read = 0;
int n;
while(total_read < num_elements && (n = fread(buffer, 1, BUFSIZE, file_id)) > 0)
{
    n = min(n, num_elements - total_read);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        s1[total_read + i] = (float)buffer[i];
    total_read += n;
}
free(buffer);
```

You might also see improved performance by using SIMD operations to convert multiple items at once.  However, the total performance will still be bottlenecked by the I/O from fread, so how much improvement you might see from SIMD will be questionable.

Since you're converting a large number of `uint8_t` values, it's all possible you could get some improved performance by using a lookup table instead of doing the integer to floating point conversion.  You'd only need a lookup table of 256 float values (1 KB), which easily fits in cache.  I don't know if that would be faster or not, so you should definitely profile the code to figure out what the best option is.